# Changing a value when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, dom

I am in the process of learning Javascript and at the moment I'm only using vanilla js to code stuff.

I'm trying to make 2 button (+ and -) to add and subtract a number.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let value = document.querySelector("#number");


let add = document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", function(value){
    add = value++;
    document.querySelector("#number").textContent = add;
});
```

With the above code, when I click my button my p tag changes to NaN. It is 0 form the start.
Goal it to make it 1.

In case you need the HTML code then this is what I have:

```
<div class="content">
 <button id="add">+</button>
 <p id="number">0</p>
 <button id="sub">-</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `global` var and `add` and `subtract` value on that.

You also need to check value is more then `zero` using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (if condition) so that the `value` is always displayed above `zero` when `subtracting`

**Live Demo**

```js
let value = document.querySelector("#number");

//Store value
let valueNumber = 0

//Add value
document.querySelector("#add").addEventListener("click", function(value) {
  valueNumber++;
  document.querySelector("#number").textContent = valueNumber;
});
 
//Subtract value
document.querySelector("#sub").addEventListener("click", function(value) {
  valueNumber--;
  document.querySelector("#number").textContent = valueNumber > 0 ? valueNumber : 0;
});
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button id="add">+</button>
  <p id="number">0</p>
  <button id="sub">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That's exactly what I wanted. I can see what I did wrong. Many thanks!

Comment: @Skossan Glad to have helped. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer has been given, I'd like to share mine.

```js
document.querySelector("#add").onclick = function(){
  let num = number.innerText;
  number.innerText = num/1 + 1;
}

document.querySelector("#sub").onclick = function(){
  let num = number.innerText;
  if(num > 0){
    number.innerText = num/1 - 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button id="add">+</button>
  <p id="number">0</p>
  <button id="sub">-</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is why I love coding. Every goal can be reached in many different ways. Which ever path you chose to take there's always something to be learned! Thanks for sharing!